# Rails - how to retrieve user's access_token from Facebook API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, access-token, facebook-access-token

When a user will sign up to my app through Facebook, I would like to display all his pages which he manage.

This is how I save data from FB API:

```
  def self.create_user_from_facebook(auth_hash)
    self.create({
      :facebook_uid => auth_hash["uid"],
      :name => auth_hash["info"]["name"],
    })
  end
```

Here how I try to print out the list of pages:

```
 - fbpages(@user).each do |page|
    = f.label :fbpage, value: page.identifier, :class => 'radio' do
      = f.radio_button :fbpage, page.identifier
      = link_to page.name, page.link, target: '_blank'
```

And the `fbpages` method:

```
def fbpages(user)
    if user.fbtoken.present?
      begin
        fbpages = FbGraph::User.me(user.fbtoken).accounts
      rescue
        user.update_attribute(:fbtoken, nil)
        fbpages = nil
      end
    end
  end
```

`fbtoken` is `access_token`. But how can I get this token? I've tried to print out what contains the `auth_hash` in the `create_user_from_facebook` method, but I don't see there the **access_token**.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can see on the [`FBGraph` page](https://github.com/criso/fbgraph):

```
// code is set
// we'll send that and get the access token
graph.authorize({
    "client_id":      conf.client_id
  , "redirect_uri":   conf.redirect_uri
  , "client_secret":  conf.client_secret
  , "code":           req.query.code
}, function (err, facebookRes) {
  res.redirect('/UserHasLoggedIn');
});
```

The `code` is included in the parameters of the redirected url a user get once he logged into your Facebook application. Once you get this `code`, you use this sample.